# How do I add an additional channel to an existing tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I have an input tensor of size [3, 3, 3, 64]. I would like to add an extra channel to the input at runtime, so that the tensor is of the form [3, 3, 4, 64]. The new channel weights can be initialized to 0.

My question is, how do I insert the new channel data to grow the channel dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`tf.concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat)

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.ones([3, 3, 3, 64]) # your original stuff
b = tf.zeros([3, 3, 1, 64])

c = tf.concat([a, b], axis=2)
print c
```

Will get `Tensor("concat_1:0", shape=(3, 3, 4, 64), dtype=float32)`